# Trying to add info (highscorelist) to a .txt file + sorting, without removing existing data

Tags: java

*This is for a uni-assignment.*

So, where do I begin?

**The task:** The assignment is to make a high schore-list that is a external .txt-file. The .txt-file can only have 5 different top scores, that means if I add a high score that's higher than the 5th place-high scorer that one needs to be deleted and replaced with the new high score.

If you click the class-name you'll get redirected to a pastie-link that includes the code.

**The problem(s):** I can not for the life of me get the code to add text without removing current text. The current statement of the code is maybe a wrong way of dealing with the problem, I dont know. I've tried several ways and none seemed to work for me (Or I was doing wrong). Sorting the list should not be a problem since I've done that in a recent assignment.

Anyways, enough chit-chat, let's get to business.

My main:

```
    public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu menu = new menu();
        menu.display();

    }
}
```

[My menu:](http://pastie.org/6035175)

```
import java.util.*;

public class menu {
    highscores highscores = new highscores();
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Make your selection!");
        System.out.println("Select an option: \n" + "  1) Insert new score\n"
                + "  2) Print list\n" + "  3) Reset list \n" + "  4) Quit\n ");

        int selection = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            highscores.enterScore();
            break;
        case 2:
            highscores.printList();
            break;
        case 3:
            highscores.resetList();
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Exiting program...");
            System.exit(1);
        default:
            System.out.println("Try Again!"); 
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

[My high score-list](http://pastie.org/6035178)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class highscores {

    public void enterScore() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the players name!: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the players score!: ");
        String score = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Player " + name + " got: " + score
                + " points. Great job!");
        try {
            File file = new File("HighScores.txt");
            PrintWriter writer;
            writer = new PrintWriter(file);
            writer.println("Player name: " +name +" - " +"Player score:" +score);
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error #1");
        }
    }


    public void printList() {
        try {
            File file = new File("Highscores.txt");
            Scanner scanner;
            if (file.exists()) {
                scanner = new Scanner(file);
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error #2");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error #1");
        }
    }

    public void resetList() {
        try {
            File file = new File("Highscores.txt");
            PrintWriter writer;
            writer = new PrintWriter(file);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                writer.println("Player name: x - Player score: x ");
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error #1");
        }

    }
}
```

Is there ANY way of saving this code and using it for this assignment?

Comment: Load old scores to memory, delete the smaller, add the new one where it fits, and overwrite **all** of the file with the new values.

Comment: Sry SJuan76, that's exactly my problem. I've tried several ways to do that and none have worked for me. I guess serialization is my answer but I have big troubles getting it to work (and belive me I've tried).

Comment: You don't need to serialize in order to do this. It should be plenty possible only using text files (and you shouldn't do it with serialization if you want the text file to be human readable after you finish). Are you having problems loading the file into memory, modifying it after it's in memory, or writing it back out after you've finished modifying it?

Comment: sage88; Exactly. I'm still struggling with the same problem atm. Something tells me that I need to start over again to be able to create a proper array for it. That is something I KNOW I have to do. Name + Score should be arrays, index = 4, and sort.randomname(); for sorting the list.

Answer (score 0):

> **The problem(s):** I can not for the life of me get the code to add text without removing current text.

Use [`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) and wrapper it within the [`PrintWriter(Writer out)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.Writer%29).

`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`'s JavaDoc:

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. ***If the second
>   argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file
>   rather than the beginning.***
>
> Parameters:
>
> file - a File object to write to
>
> append - ***if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file
>   rather than the beginning***

---

Update your code:

```
PrintWriter writer;
writer = new PrintWriter(file);
```

to:

```
PrintWriter writer;
writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

Comment: But he will  end having 6 top players... what he needs is to overwrite the file

Comment: Yeah actually I thought this is what he wanted to do at first also, but he should be overwriting the file each time, not appending. If he appends it won't change the scores, it will just add new ones.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it this evening to solve the problem. I'll tell you later how it worked out.

Comment: This was not really what I needed. The assignment is to replace the highscorelist each time so I dont get 6> top players